# Is it possible to ack nagios alerts from the terminal on a remote workstation?

Tags: nagios

I have nagios alerts set up to come through jabber with an http link to ack.

Is is possible there is a script I can run from a terminal on a remote workstation that takes the hostname as a parameter and acks the alert?

./ack hostname

The benefit, while seemingly mundane, is threefold. First, take http load off nagios. Secondly, nagios http pages can take up to 10-20 seconds to load, so I want to save time there. Thirdly, avoiding slower use of mouse + web interface + firefox/other annoyingly slow browser.

Ideally, I would like a script bound to a keyboard shortcut that simply acks the most recent alert. Finally, I want to take the inputs from a joystick, buttons and whatnot, and connect one to a big red button bound to the script so I can just ack the most recent nagios alert by hitting the button lol. (It would be rad too if the button had a screen on the enclosure that showed the text of the alert getting acked lol)

Make fun of me all you want, but this is actually something that would be useful to me. If I can save five seconds per alert, and I get 200 alerts per day I need to ack, that's saving me 15 minutes a day. And isn't the whole point of the sysadmin to automate what can be automated?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is definitely possible, but keep in mind that you are diving into the innards of Nagios which have a steep learning curve. It should be an interesting and rewarding learning curve.

You can make use of the Nagios [External Commands](http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/extcommands.html) to allow external programs to insert commands into the Nagios command queue. There are [many commands](http://old.nagios.org/developerinfo/externalcommands/commandlist.php). Combine this with remote access and the possibilities from the command line and shell scripting, and the possibilities are quite large.

Here's one example: From a remote box, SSH into the Nagios host. The command `~/bin/ack` will insert a command into the [command_file](http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/configmain.html#command_file) queue. Nagios will then read the command_file, and execute your command. The command might look something like:

`ssh nagios.example.org ~/bin/ack hostA`

Another example: To disable all notifications on Nagios from a remote host, the command is something like:

`ssh nagios.example.org "echo \"[\"`date +%s`\"] DISABLE_NOTIFICATIONS\" > /var/spool/nagios/cmd/nagios.cmd"`

You could in theory do this with other daemons as well, make use of Netcat to listen on a port and pipe commands into a file, or even do this using Jabber, IRC, etc. I know one group who did this using xinitd listening on certain ports. Be *very careful* to consider the security implications of allowing unauthenticated remote access to your Nagios host.

Nagios has more information on external commands in the manual. See [Nagios Core: External Commands](http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/extcommands.html)

Here's an example for [executing commands from Munin](http://munin-monitoring.org/wiki/HowToContactNagios). They make use of [NSCA](http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Addons/Passive-Checks/NSCA--2D-Nagios-Service-Check-Acceptor/details)

Comment: This looks great, thanks for the help! I will try this.

Answer (score 1):

If security is not your priority, some netcat + xinetd + script each side will do. If you want some security and/or you don't want to write it yourself, you may want to give [NRCD](http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Addons/External-Commands/Nagios-remote-external-command-daemon/details) or [nscaweb](https://github.com/smetj/nscaweb) a try. Or take a look at this script named [nagios_commander](https://github.com/brandoconnor/nagios_commander/blob/master/nagios_commander.sh)

Answer (score 0):

With things as distributed in the standard core, I'd say no.  But if you expand the cgi.c and supporting module code for the website, you might be able to do this.  The URI might not look pretty.  A possible problem would be the request for authentication for authorization to perform the command.

Have you checked out the nagios exchange site and maybe post something there?